# Opencv does not draw nice antialiased line

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to get a nice smoothed line with the `line()` function of opencv but the line gets rough (see the picture). I'm using `opencv 3.1.0` and following :

```
for x, y in outline : 
    if prevX < 0 and prevY < 0 :
        prevX = x
        prevY = y
        continue
    whitedrop = cv2.line(whitedrop, (int(prevX), int(prevY)), (int(x), int(y)), (141, 141,  141), 1, cv2.LINE_AA  )
    prevX = x
    prevY = y
```

Here comes the result. Im talking about the outline only. It does not look like antialiased for me :

[image]

Any Ideas on what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using [`polylines`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines) ?

Comment: How will it help get antialiased line?

Comment: It would maybe improve your code. Whats your image type?

Comment: @PSchn output is JPEG

Comment: I meant is it an grayscale image, or flaoting point ... check with image.type() and look up [here](http://ninghang.blogspot.de/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html?m=1)